# Помогите разобраться с переносом слов

Tags: c++, c, массивы

Есть программа, которая хорошо работает с небольшим объемом текста

Мне нужно было сделать так, чтобы, когда происходило превышение по памяти, программа удаляла часть текста из массива, сдвигая его.

Программа: 1я строка - то что ищем
Далее текст в котором ищем

Проблема заключается в левых числах при разбиении текста

Очень надеюсь на вашу помощь!

```
  // STD и стандартные библиотеки
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdbool.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cctype>
    #include <cstring>

    struct Word {
        char Text[50];
        unsigned int pos;
        unsigned int line;
    };

    // Структура списка слов
    struct WordList {
        unsigned int count;
        struct Word * Words;
    };


    const int WordLength = 75;            // Максимальная длина одного слова
    const unsigned int RAMLimit = 1000;//2147483648;    // Ограничение по памяти
    const double RAMreserv = 5;            // Сколько RAM зарезервированно (в %)

        unsigned int x = 0;
        unsigned int y = 1;


    // Сигнатуры функций
    unsigned int GetSubStr(struct WordList * WL);
    bool GetTextPrt(struct WordList * WL, unsigned int AvMemory);
    void Z_FUC(struct WordList * WL, unsigned int SubStrCount);
    void Cutter(struct WordList * WL, unsigned int SubStrCount);


    // Основной цикл
    int main() {
        // Переменные
        struct WordList MainStr;
        unsigned int AvMemory = (unsigned int)(RAMLimit * (1-(RAMreserv / 100)));
        unsigned int SubStrCount;
        bool exitkey = true;

        // Инициализация MainStr
        MainStr.count = 0;
        MainStr.Words = (struct Word*)malloc(15*sizeof(struct Word));

        // Ввод подстроки + резерв места под уникальное слово
        AvMemory -= GetSubStr(&MainStr);

        // Сохранить длину постоянной части
        SubStrCount = MainStr.count;

        // Считываем и обрабатываем дальнейшие строки
        while (exitkey){
            // Cчитываем допустимый объем
            exitkey = GetTextPrt(&MainStr, AvMemory/2);

            // Включаем Z-функцию и выводим результат
            Z_FUC(&MainStr, SubStrCount);

            // Обрезка строки
            Cutter(&MainStr, SubStrCount);
        }

        free(MainStr.Words);

        return 0;
    }


    // Заполнение подстроки
    unsigned int GetSubStr(struct WordList * WL) {
        // Переменные
        char Char;
        bool exitkey = false;
        unsigned int i = 0;
        unsigned int freeblocks = 0;

        while (!exitkey) {
            // Cчитывание символа
            Char = toupper(getchar_unlocked());
            // Если нет места
            if (freeblocks == 0) {
                freeblocks = (unsigned int)(WL->count * 1.25 + 1);
                WL->Words = (struct Word *)realloc(WL->Words, (WL->count + freeblocks) * sizeof(struct Word));
            }

            // Если символ - добавляем
            if (((Char >= 'A') && (Char <= 'Z')) || ((Char >= '0') && (Char <= '9'))) {
                WL->Words[WL->count].Text[i] = Char;
                i++;
            }
            else

            // Если символ - пробел
            if (((Char == ' ') || (Char == '\t')) && (i > 0)) {
                freeblocks--;
                WL->Words[WL->count].Text[i] = 0;
                i = 0;
                WL->count++;
            }

            // Если символ - переход на новую строку
            if (Char == '\n') {
                if (i > 0) {
                    freeblocks--;
                    WL->Words[WL->count].Text[i] = 0;
                    i = 0;
                    WL->count++;
                }
                exitkey = true;
            }
            else

            // Если это конец ввода
            if (Char == EOF) {
                if (i > 0) {
                    freeblocks--;
                    WL->Words[WL->count].Text[i] = 0;
                    i = 0;
                    WL->count++;
                }
                exitkey = true;
            }

        }
        WL->Words = (struct Word *)realloc(WL->Words, (WL->count + 1) * sizeof(struct Word));
        WL->count++;
        // Добавить уникальное слово
        sprintf(WL->Words[WL->count - 1].Text, "%s", "@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@");
        WL->Words[WL->count - 1].line = 0;
        WL->Words[WL->count - 1].pos = 0;



        return (WL->count * sizeof(struct Word));

    }


    // Заполнение остальных строк
    bool GetTextPrt(struct WordList * WL, unsigned int AvMemory) {
        // Переменные
        char Char;
        bool exitkey = false;
        unsigned int i = 0;
        unsigned int freeblocks = 0;

        while (!exitkey){
            // Cчитывание символа
            Char = toupper(getchar_unlocked());
            // Если нет места
            if (freeblocks == 0) {
                freeblocks = (unsigned int)(WL->count * 1.25 + 1);
                WL->Words = (struct Word *)realloc(WL->Words, (WL->count+freeblocks)*sizeof(struct Word));
            }

            // Доп. определение EOF
            if (Char == '@') Char = EOF;

            // Если символ - добавляем
            if (((Char >= 'A') && (Char <= 'Z')) || ((Char >= '0') && (Char <= '9'))) {
                WL->Words[WL->count].Text[i] = Char;
                i++;
            }
            else

            // Если память закончилась
            if (AvMemory < WL->count * sizeof(struct Word)) Char = EOF; else

            // Если символ - пробел
            if (((Char == ' ')|| (Char == '\t'))&&(i>0)){
                freeblocks--;
                WL->Words[WL->count].Text[i] = 0;
                i = 0;
                x++;
                WL->Words[WL->count].pos = x;
                WL->Words[WL->count].line = y;
                WL->count++;
            }

            // Если символ - переход на новую строку
            if (Char == '\n') {
                if (i > 0) {
                    freeblocks--;
                    WL->Words[WL->count].Text[i] = 0;
                    i = 0;
                    x++;
                    WL->Words[WL->count].pos = x;
                    WL->Words[WL->count].line = y;
                    WL->count++;
                }
                y++;
                x = 0;
            } else

            // Если это конец ввода
            if (Char == EOF){
                if (i > 0) {
                    freeblocks--;
                    WL->Words[WL->count].Text[i] = 0;
                    i = 0;
                    x++;
                    WL->Words[WL->count].pos = x;
                    WL->Words[WL->count].line = y;
                    WL->count++;
                }
                exitkey = true;
            }

        }
        WL->Words = (struct Word *)realloc(WL->Words, (WL->count) * sizeof(struct Word));

        return (AvMemory < WL->count * sizeof(struct Word));
    }


    // Функция минимума (служебная)
    unsigned int GetMin(unsigned int l, unsigned int r) {
        if (l <= r) return l; else return r;
    }

    // Сравнить строки (служебная)
    bool smp(const char *str1, const char *str2) {
        return (strcmp(str1, str2) == 0);
    }

    // Запуск Z функции и вывод результата
    void Z_FUC(struct WordList * WL, unsigned int SubStrCount) {
        // Переменные
        unsigned int* DStr;
        unsigned int i; // Тикер для циклов
        unsigned int left = 0; // Необходимо для Z-function
        unsigned int right = 0; // Необходимо для Z-function


        /* Z-функция */

        // Инициализация
        DStr = (unsigned int*)malloc(WL->count*sizeof(unsigned int));
        for (i = 0; i < WL->count; i++) DStr[i] = 0;

        // Работа шайтан машины
        for (i = 1; i < WL->count; ++i) {

            if (i <= right) DStr[i] = GetMin(right - i + 1, DStr[i - left]);

            while (((i + DStr[i]) < WL->count) && (smp(WL->Words[DStr[i]].Text, WL->Words[i + DStr[i]].Text))) {
                ++(DStr[i]);
            }

            if (i + DStr[i] - 1 > right) {
                left = i;
                right = i + DStr[i] - 1;
            }
        }

        // Вывод ответа
        for (i = 0; i < (WL->count - SubStrCount); i++){
            if (DStr[i + SubStrCount] == SubStrCount - 1) {
                printf("%u%s%d%c", WL->Words[i + SubStrCount].line, ", ", WL->Words[i + SubStrCount].pos, '\n');
             }
        }

    }

    void Cutter(struct WordList * WL, unsigned int SubStrCount) {
        // Переменные
        unsigned int i;
            for (i = 0; i < SubStrCount-2; i++) {
                WL->Words[SubStrCount + i].line = WL->Words[WL->count - (SubStrCount - 2) + i].line;
                WL->Words[SubStrCount + i].pos = WL->Words[WL->count - (SubStrCount - 2) + i].pos;
                sprintf(WL->Words[SubStrCount + i].Text, "%s", WL->Words[WL->count - (SubStrCount - 2) + i].Text);
            }
            WL->Words = (struct Word*)realloc(WL->Words, (2*SubStrCount-1)*sizeof(struct Word));
            WL->count = 2 * SubStrCount - 2;
    }
```

Comment: *Проблема заключается в левых числах при разбиении текста* - кто-то понял, о чём говорит TS?

Comment: @Sergey Смотрите: Принахождении вхождения - программа выводит номер строки и слова вхождения

Comment: @Sergey однако, когда подается текст превышающий ограничение по памяти (Для удобство ввыерху уменьшить до 1000) то можно наблюдать или левые числа или ерись какую-то, причем только среди первых чисел, дальше они вроде не врут

Comment: *можно наблюдать или левые* - вопрос слишком общий. Я не думаю, что кто-то будет тщательно разбирать ВЕСЬ Ваш код в поисках ошибки.  Можно уточнить проблему?

Comment: Есть две функции GetTextPrt (загрузка текста)и Cutter(очистка ненужного текста). Где-то в них ошибка, из-за чего страдает вывод вхождений.
А как исправить и где она - никак не найду :(

Comment: @Sergey еще судя по всему все дело в SEG FAULT но вызвать его повторно никак не получается

Comment: Если выскакивает SEG FAULT, то это - 100% неправильное использование указателей. Или выход за границы массива. Советую вам скомпилировать программу с опцией отладки (-g), запустить под отладчиком, а когда она рухнет - попросить отладчик распечатать стек вызовов.  Он Вам покажет строку, в которой произошла ошибка. Дальше думать Вам...

Comment: @Sergey как выяснилось - продлема была в нехватке оперативной памяти у компьютера